# Dispersion relation for Rayleigh equation given unbounded vortex sheet

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, calculus, dispersion

Reference: Drazin and Reid

Consider Rayleigh's equation away from the continuous part of the spectrum, which is governed by $$\phi''-\alpha^2\phi=0.$$ Given the shear flow $U(z)=\text{sgn } z$, one has solutions of the form $\phi=Ae^{-\alpha z}$ for $z>0$ and $\phi=Be^{\alpha z}$ for $z<0.$ The authors state that if we apply the matching conditions $$\Delta(\phi/(U-c))=0,\qquad \Delta ((U-c)\phi'-U'\phi)=0$$ at $z=0$, where $\Delta$ indicates the jump over the interface (i.e. the difference of the one-sided limits), then we get the eigenvalue equation $c^2+1=0.$ I am having trouble deriving this. I am getting the following from the jump conditions: $$\frac{1}{1-c}-\frac{1}{-1-c}=0,\qquad 2\alpha c=0,$$
which are both obviously incorrect. I obtained the above using the following computations:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0^\pm}e^{\mp \alpha z}&=1,\\
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0^\pm}\frac{d}{dz}e^{\mp \alpha z}&=\mp \alpha,\\
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0^\pm} U(z)&=\pm 1,\\
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0^\pm} U'(z)&"="0.
\end{align*}

I must be making some stupid calculus mistakes but am not seeing them right now. Or am I misinterpreting the matching conditions?

EDIT: Figured it out, posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I shouldn't have dropped the coefficients $A$ and $B$. If we keep them in the calculations, we get a matrix equation of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix}1+c && 1-c\\ \alpha c+\alpha && \alpha c+\alpha \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A\\ B\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$ The determinant of the matrix is $$2\alpha (c^2+1).$$ Setting this equal to zero in order to get a unique solution to the matrix equation gives the correct eigenvalue equation if $\alpha\neq 0.$ In fact, we get from here that $A=iB,$ so removing them (implicitly assuming that they're the same) is fatal.